# Pipe filepath to ImageJ

Tags: bash, macos

I have a little command line utility `rjp2tif` that extracts radiometric data from a jpeg file into a tiff file. I was hoping to be able to pipe the filepath to ImageJ on the command line and have ImageJ open the tiff file. To this end, `rjp2tif` writes the filepath of the tiff file to standard output. I tried the following in bash:

`$ rjp2tif /path/to/rjpeg | open -a imagej`

and

`$ rjp2tif /path/to/rjpeg | open -a imagej -f`

The first opens ImageJ but doesn't open the file.
The second opens ImageJ with a text window with the filepath in it.

This is on macOS Monterey, but I don't think that matters.
Anyone tried to do this and been successful? TIA.

Comment: I imagine you'd want `open -a imagej "$(rjp2tif /path/to/rjpeg)"`

Comment: Or you could do `rjp2tif /path/to/rjpeg | xargs open -a imagej` ?

Comment: It would be more... _main stream?_ to add a second argument to `rjp2tif` for saving its output, so that you can use it like this: `rjp2tif /path/to/rjpeg /path/to/tiff`

Comment: ErikMD and Mark Setchell Ok both of those methods work. I thought I had tried xargs command before. I guess I'll have to read the man page to see how xargs works. ErikMD you could post that as an answer and I would accept it. @Fravadona the tiff file is saved in the same folder as the rjpeg file.

Comment: Do you have a link to rjp2tif? I can't find any info about it - and it sounds really useful.

Comment: @Terence Eden  Just noticed your comment. That rjp2tif code was for a very expensive Flir lab camera. Probably not useful for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `rjp2tif` command returns a file-path in standard output, and you want to pass this output as a regular CLI argument to another command, you may be interested in the [`xargs`](https://ss64.com/osx/xargs.html) command.  But note that in the general case, you may hit some issue if the file-path contains spaces or so:

> Read space, tab, newline and end-of-file delimited arguments from standard input and execute the specified utility with them as arguments.
> The arguments are typically a long list of filenames (generated by `ls` or `find`, for example) that get passed to `xargs` via a pipe.

So in this case, assuming each file-path takes only one line (which is obviously the case if there's only one line overall), you can use the following `NUL`-based tip relying on the [`tr`](https://ss64.com/osx/tr.html) command.

Here is the command you'd obtain:

```sh
rjp2tif /path/to/rjpeg | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 open -a imagej
```

Note: I have a GNU/Linux OS, so can you please confirm it does work under macOS?

FTR, below is a comprehensive shell code allowing one to test two different modes of `xargs`: generating one command per line-argument (`-n1`), or a single command with all line-arguments in one go:

```sh
$ printf 'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 \
  bash -c 'printf "Run "; for a; do printf "\"$a\" "; done; echo' bash
Run "one " 
Run "two" 
Run "three and four" 

$ printf 'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 \
  bash -c 'printf "Run "; for a; do printf "\"$a\" "; done; echo' bash
Run "one " "two" "three and four" 

######################################
# or alternatively (with no for loop):
######################################

$ printf 'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 \
  bash -c 'printf "Run "; printf "\"%s\" " "$@"; echo' bash
Run "one " 
Run "two" 
Run "three and four" 

$ printf 'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 \
  bash -c 'printf "Run "; printf "\"%s\" " "$@"; echo' bash
Run "one " "two" "three and four"
```

Comment: @ErickMD Yes, the `tr` command you have above does work on macOS, thanks. I found that the `-t` option (trace) to `xargs` is helpful to show what `xargs` does to the command. In the case here, when `path/to/tiff` is passed to `xargs` via the pipe, `xargs` rearranges the command to `open -a imagej path/to/tiff`. Very useful.

Comment: @ErickMD One additional thing, you mentioned above that there is one line to standard output from `rjp2tif` that is piped to `xargs`. However there could be many lines to standard output if I use a `-v` option to `rjp2tif`. This can work also if I use `tee /dev/tty` to show all lines on the screen followed by `tail -n 1` to just get the last line for piping to `xargs`. In this case the command line is: `rjp2tif -v /path/to/rjpeg | tee /dev/tty | tail -n 1 | xargs open -a imagej`. I left out the `tr` command for simplification.

Comment: Yes, but `xargs` can also support multiple lines in input as I mentioned in my answer, and you have 2 choices in this case: either run one `open` command for each file → `xargs -0 -n1 open -a imagej`; or run a single `open` command with all files passed as args → `xargs -0 open -a imagej`. So you don't need `tail -n 1` at all (unless you are interested in only one file, of course)

Comment: Actually I guess I misinterpreted your remark: with the `-v` option, you don't have several file-paths involved, but just some additional "noise" that can be removed from stdout by using `tail -n 1`, indeed.

Comment: Yes, `rjp2tif` just works with one file at present. The `-v` is for verbose. So the "noise" is a print out of metadata for the file. I guess I could try and make `rjp2tif` work for multiple files.